# how can i change value of 3d matrix where it has zero in all layer in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix

assume that i got matrix ,called mat.

```
mat(:,:,1) =

     0     1     0     1     0
     1     0     1     1     0
     1     0     1     0     1
     1     1     1     1     0
     0     0     1     1     1

mat(:,:,2) =

     1     1     0     1     1
     0     1     1     0     1
     0     1     1     0     1
     1     0     1     1     1
     0     0     0     0     0

mat(:,:,3) =

     1     0     0     1     1
     1     1     0     0     0
     1     1     1     1     0
     0     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1
```

i want to change value in each layer where it has zero in all 3 layers.

```
mat_result(:,:,1) =

     0     1    -1     1     0
     1     0     1     1     0
     1     0     1     0     1
     1     1     1     1     0
    -1    -1     1     1     1

mat_result(:,:,2) =

     1     1    -1     1     1
     0     1     1     0     1
     0     1     1     0     1
     1     0     1     1     1
    -1    -1     0     0     0


mat_result(:,:,3) =

     1     0    -1     1     1
     1     1     0     0     0
     1     1     1     1     0
     0     1     0     0     0
    -1    -1     0     0     1
```

First, i find the position

```
ind = find(mat(:,:,1)==0 & mat(:,:,2)==0 & mat(:,:,3)==0)

ind =

     5
    10
    11
```

In the simple way, i do this

```
matt1 = mat(:,:,1);
matt2 = mat(:,:,2);
matt3 = mat(:,:,3);
matt1(ind) = -1;
matt2(ind) = -1;
matt3(ind) = -1;

mat_result = cat(3,matt1,matt2,matt3);
```

My question is

1. Is there a better ways to choose/change submatrix of submatrix?
   for example(but it didn't work):

   `mat(:,:,1)(mat(:,:,1)==0 & mat(:,:,2)==0 & mat(:,:,3)==0) = -1;`
2. Is there a shorter way to change value in each layer where it has zero in all 3 layers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mat(repmat(~any(mat,3),[1,1,3]))=-1
```

Instead of using `mat(:,:,1)==0 & mat(:,:,2)==0 & mat(:,:,3)==0` you may use the `any` function.

Comment: And is there a way to choose submatrix from submatrix? (in my first question)

Comment: @BOSS No idea what the code from the first question should do. Please describe the intended output.

Comment: for my first question, output that i want is the same as mat_result(:;:;1)

Comment: especially, I want to change value in the 1st layer but I must consider all 3 layer. And i did as above.(find index -> matt1 = mat(:;:;1) -> matt1(ind) = -1)

Comment: i think that there may be a way that i can use this =>> mat(:,:,1)(ind). to change some component in submetrix using 1 line code.

Answer (score 3):

Use the repmat function to replicate the logical matrix you get by using

```
mat(:,:,1)==0 & mat(:,:,2)==0 & mat(:,:,3)==0.
```

Replicate it along the 3rd channel. Final statement is:

```
mat(repmat(mat(:,:,1)==0 & mat(:,:,2)==0 & mat(:,:,3)==0,[1 1 3]))=-1
```